# Add custom link to a page

Tags: navigation

I am not able to find out how can I add a custom link at the bottom of a page (like in the image below - "hlee's blog"). When I click on the 'Edit' tab, there is not html/code for that link. I need to add another link on this page but have no clue where the setting/code is.

[image: custom link]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using Drupal 7. Many ways to do this, one way is to implement [hook_node_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7)

Comment: Yes, it is Drupal 7. I am fairly new to Drupal. When you say implement 'hook_node_view', do you mean programmatically?

Comment: @VaibhavGathibandhe yes

Comment: Is there a contributed module I can install to achieve this?

Comment: @VaibhavGathibandhe you need to implement this hook in your custom module. Please read about drupal module development. The answer for your question is in the link above